# React, navigate to react-bootstrap tab with history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I'm writing a multi-form page (login/registration/lost-password) using tabs (react-bootstrap).

react 17.0.2, react-bootstrap 2.2.1, react-router-dom 6.2.2

I try to implement the tab selection with url/history. I used this :

route :

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        childRoutes: [
            { path: '/', component: <HomePage />, isIndex: true },
            { path: '/user/:active_tab',  component: <LoginPage /> },
        ],
    },
];
```

history :

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

LoginPage :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import styles from './styles';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import history from '../../../common/history';

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function LoginPage() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    
    const { active_tab } = useParams();
    //let [ activeTab, setActiveTab ] = useState(active_tab);
    const DEFAULT_INITIAL_TAB = 'login';

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!active_tab) {
          history.push(`/user/${DEFAULT_INITIAL_TAB}`);
        }
    }, [])

    const toggle = tab => {
        if (active_tab != tab) {
            history.push(`/user/${tab}`);
        }
        //setActiveTab(tab);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="card mt-3" style={{ width:"550px" }}>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <Tabs
                        id="login-page-tabs"
                        activeKey={active_tab} //{activeTab}
                        onSelect={toggle}
                        className="mb-3">
                        <Tab eventKey="login" title={t('Login-Title')}>
                            <LoginForm />
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="register" title={t('Register-Title')}>
                            REGISTER
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="lostpassword" title={t('LostPassword-Title')}>
                            LOST PASSWORD
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My problem is the following :
When using "as is", clicking on a tab won't display the correct tab. Only <Link to={"user/login"} /> (in header for example) is working to display the correct tab.

When removing comments on

```
let [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState();
setActiveTab(tab); // in toggle function
```

and replacing {active_tab} by {activeTab} in Tabs properties, the behaviors is inverted... Clicking on tabs show the correct display, but Link in header won't work...

history always work by replacing old tab key by new tab key (login, register, lostpassword).

I don't understand how to let all working together... I'm new to react, maybe the way I try to take is not correct ? If anyone has a suggestions...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you are using `react-router-dom@6` but interacting with a history object directly, have you instantiated the low-level `Router` correctly? Can you include a more [complete and comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? If possible, could you also provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @drew-reese. These are my first steps into react, so be lenient with me :)
here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-dream-jenbp2) to demonstrate the project.
When you use the "login" header link you will be redirected to the "LoginPage" component. click on the register / lost password and it display correct screens. But if you click on the "login" header link another time, it don't change the screen to loginForm component...

Comment: Ok so finally I can maybe answer to myself, with your help. react-router-dom@6 use "useNavigate" instead of "useHistory" from tutorials I followed. By using: const navigate = useNavigate(); and replace any "history.push("path/to/navigate") calls by "navigate("path/to/navigate"), it seems working well. Thanks on pointing the history object interaction.

Comment: Affirmative, sorry I wasn't able to respond more quickly. I've provided an answer below along with an explanation with what the issue/cause was.

Answer (score 0):

While you've created and exported a custom `history` object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

This isn't the same history object instance that the `BrowserRouter` component instantiates and uses itself:

[BrowswerRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/7dca9dc38c837ed94796325b1e0582aa72a9313f/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L139-L169)

> ```
> /**
>  * A `<Router>` for use in web browsers. Provides the cleanest URLs.
>  */
> export function BrowserRouter({
>   basename,
>   children,
>   window,
> }: BrowserRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createBrowserHistory({ window }); // <-- the history object the Router uses!
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location,
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

When you import *your* `history` object and issue imperative navigation actions it will update the URL, as expected, but because it isn't the history context your router is using it isn't aware of any of the navigation actions occurring.

The solution is rather simple/trivial, import and use the `useNavigate` hook which replaced the `react-router-dom@5` `useHistory` hook and exposes a `navigate` function.

Example:

```
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const DEFAULT_INITIAL_TAB = "login";

export default function LoginPage() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- access the navigate function

  const { active_tab } = useParams();
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(active_tab);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!active_tab) {
      navigate(`/user/${DEFAULT_INITIAL_TAB}`); // <-- PUSH action
    }
    setActiveTab(active_tab);
  }, [active_tab, navigate]);

  //console.log('initial tab : ' + init);
  const toggle = (tab) => {
    if (active_tab !== tab) {
      navigate(`/user/${tab}`); // <-- PUSH action
    }
    setActiveTab(tab);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card mt-3" style={{ width: "550px" }}>
        <div className="card-body">
          <Tabs
            id="login-page-tabs"
            activeKey={activeTab}
            onSelect={toggle}
            className="mb-3"
          >
            <Tab eventKey="login" title={t("Login-Title")}>
              <LoginForm />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="register" title={t("Register-Title")}>
              REGISTER
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="lostpassword" title={t("LostPassword-Title")}>
              LOST PASSWORD
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-navigate-to-react-bootstrap-tab-with-history]

If you don't want to "pollute" the history stack with a bunch of entries navigating between tabs you can use a redirect (*REPLACE*) instead of PUSH actions.

Example:

```
navigate(`/user/${tab}`, { replace: true });
```